# Ao clicar em um botão abrir conteúdo em uma div ao clicar em outro botão apagar o conteudo da div e abrir o novo

Tags: jquery

Gente estou a dois dias tentando programar uma sequencia de botões cada um desses botões tem que abrir um conteudo em uma div ao lado deles e quando clicado em outro apagar o conteúdo anterior e exiber um novo. Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Várias pessoas aqui conseguem te ajudar. Em parte esse é o espírito do site, mas para isso precisaremos saber o que já tentou fazer. Você pode acessar o botão [edit] e adicionar o seu código. Para formatá-lo corretamente, basta adicionar 4 espaços no início de cada linha ou selecioná-lo e pressionar o botão `{}` do editor. Se for um código mais simples, pode arriscar a utilizar o *snippet* através do botão `</>` do editor, inserindo os códigos HTML e JavaScript.

Comment: Minha resposta é uma cortesia de boas-vindas, mas da próxima vez procure se adequar ao site lendo esse post https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
//SCRIPT

    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("a").click(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass("same-box")) {
          $(".toggle:visible").slideUp();
          $($(this).attr("href")).slideDown();
          return false;
        }
        var myelement = $(this).attr("href");
        $(myelement).slideToggle("fast");
        $(".toggle:visible").not(myelement).slideUp();
      });
    });
```

```css
//CSS
.toggle { display: none; } 
.same-box-1 { display: none; }
```

```html
<!--HTML-->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <table border="0" align="center">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="#box1"><button>Mostrar div 1</button></a></td>
          <td><a href="#box2"><button>Mostrar div 2</button></a></td>
          <td><a href="#box3"><button>Mostrar div 3</button></a></td>
          <td><a href="#box4"><button>Mostrar div 4</button></a></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    
  <div class="same-box-1 toggle" id="box1">
 <p>O tempo deixa perguntas, mostra respostas, esclarece dúvidas.</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="same-box-1 toggle" id="box2">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer sit nec dignissim ligula blandit, mauris et massa lacus sed eu fusce, non aliquet aenean et, ultricies pellentesque vel nam, velit erat ut tincidunt curae tincidunt. Blandit orci,    potenti quis quis maecenas. Etiam a interdum malesuada orci, justo sit aliquam est amet praesent magna, etiam rutrum in semper aut. Mi tempus eu molestie lorem dignissim, aenean in ante mi, nam porttitor nonummy     condimentum et a, sit dictumst, sem sem massa. Vehicula libero ut in orci aenean eleifend, ipsum placerat, platea risus, amet tincidunt, pellentesque dolor id sed facilisi faucibus. Libero cum nec aliquam vitae dictum    habitasse, metus aliquam, nunc sit ut elit at, feugiat fusce viverra tempus posuere, porttitor et ac fringilla magna eget posuere. Porttitor vehicula, dignissim natoque, lectus lobortis felis habitant integer maecenas    luctus, et viverra adipiscing in. Vitae habitasse penatibus vitae, scelerisque fermentum ipsum leo adipiscing tincidunt, nisl turpis consectetuer. Vel nullam vivamus eleifend, mi praesent ac. Placerat varius hymenaeos    vestibulum vitae ullamcorper. Nulla ornare nulla auctor, ut eleifend porta quis nonummy fringilla sit, pellentesque tortor nulla curabitur duis.</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="same-box-1 toggle" id="box3">
        <p>Sollicitudin egestas sed auctor lacus in, congue consectetuer et eu dolor aliquet vitae, diam ac mattis, dui proin consequat vel quisque quisque cum. Eget vestibulum at litora. Nulla tincidunt facilisi potenti vel, massa    eget mi vel dui ante, mattis vitae ad nunc, nulla nibh erat id consectetuer, viverra risus velit dolor eros elementum malesuada. Vitae leo fusce nec eu viverra, ipsum erat justo habitasse ut velit. In congue euismod in,    donec augue, platea cras donec elit urna ut turpis, sapien tincidunt aenean consequat. Libero eros vestibulum metus justo dui veniam, orci fusce, eget at ut. Dolor consequat enim, scelerisque donec pulvinar scelerisque.    Justo sit. In dis a nullam, vel pede sit vel. Risus rhoncus justo, laboris egestas vitae sit mauris, amet vitae nunc, vivamus vel eleifend at dignissim quis lacus, sit lacus lacus.</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="same-box-1 toggle" id="box4">
        <p>Orci laoreet ipsum integer mattis magna, egestas egestas eu dui felis vivamus lorem, morbi fermentum in leo et, interdum sollicitudin, pellentesque massa elit. Wisi luctus, sed praesent sed etiam, in quisque ac nam wisi    est, in scelerisque nullam urna et. Donec adipiscing, nullam ut eget integer, pellentesque sem, malesuada et magnis, sed sed urna mattis. Aenean et odio, massa quis ipsum, vitae a nibh excepturi etiam rutrum, maecenas    laoreet eleifend wisi orci mi, tortor urna. Perferendis justo luctus quis volutpat sed ligula. Sociis non rutrum justo turpis a sed, felis amet ut velit erat duis rutrum, arcu eros wisi a consectetuer eros, vitae     aliquam. Nulla elit mus cras mauris, elementum donec interdum turpis eget euismod, tempus quis. Faucibus varius, luctus dictum mauris vel ullamcorper placerat. Torquent in tempor</p>
  </div>
```

> Melhor visualizado se clicar em `Pagina toda` após clicar em `Executar`

- `$(document).ready(function() {` como quase tudo o que fazemos quando estamos utilizando o jQuery lê ou manipula um modelo de objeto de documento (DOM), precisamos nos certificar que começamos adicionado eventos etc tão logo o DOM esteja pronto.
- `$("a")` é um seletor do jQuery, neste caso, ele seleciona todos os elementos `a`. O `$` por si só é um alias para a "classe" jQuery, por outro lado o `$()` constrói um novo objeto jQuery. A função `click()` que chamamos depois é um método do objeto jQuery. Ele liga o evento clique a todos os elementos selecionados (neste caso, um único elemento `a`) e executa a função fornecida quando o evento ocorre.
- `hasClass()` checa se um ou vários elementos já tem uma classe específica definida
- Um efeito muito utilizado com a jQuery é o `Slide`. O `slideDown` faz a animação caindo, o `slideUp`, faz a animação subindo e o `slideToggle` faz o elemento HTML subir ou descer dependendo se ele estiver retraído ou não.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize:

```
function TrocaDivs
{
  $('#idDaDivQueVaiDesaparecer').css("display","none");
  $('#idDaDivQueVaiAparecer').css("display","block")
}
```

E chama no botão que você quer a função com o `onclick`, porexemplo:

```
<button onclick="TrocaDivs();"> </button>
```